# Add Trailing Slash to Posts

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using following .htaccess code to add trailing slash all urls but homepage.

```
## Base Redirects ##

# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Include trailing slash on non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://hamilekadin.net/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash from directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ https://hamilekadin.net/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hamilekadin.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want non-www url's, https protocol and trailing slash after post and page url's.

With this .htaccess I'm getting **404 error** on categories, pages, posts.

Also my permalink type is: **/%postname%/**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for trailing slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://yourdomainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For non-www url,there are two option

**Option 1 :**

You need to run SQL query to remove www  from url

**Option 2**

Add following code in .htacess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

According to me to remove www most preferable way is option 1 where you just need to run the query.

Comment: Trailing Slash code is not working. @a-shah

Comment: What is the error have you changed the url?

Comment: There should be "/" after $1, shouldn't be?

With these, getting an error. It's not redirecting http to https and also error on posts.

Comment: I this the second line is missing with https url

Comment: Not working. Check it out on httpstatus.io